# I want to make splash screen and now I have two problems?

Tags: c++, c, screen, x11, splash-screen

1: I want to have a splash screen but I only have a window？so,how to do with sth like parm

2: I've used a while(!done) to draw the window so how to break out with a function or sth else

here is my code and much thx to you

g++ -o m_splash m_splash.cpp -lX11 -lImlib2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <Imlib2.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    Imlib_Image  m_img;
    Display     *m_dpy;
    Pixmap       m_pix;
    Window       m_root;
    Screen      *scn;
    int m_width, m_height;
    const char *filename = "/home/ang/so_zt/w.png";

    m_img = imlib_load_image(filename);
    if(!m_img)
    {
        printf("%s\n","init m_img faild");
    }
    imlib_context_set_image(m_img);
    m_width = imlib_image_get_width();
    m_height = imlib_image_get_height();

    m_dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if(!m_dpy)
    {
        printf("%s\n","open display failed");
    }
    scn = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(m_dpy);
    int s = DefaultScreen(m_dpy);
    m_root = XCreateSimpleWindow(m_dpy, RootWindow(m_dpy,s),10,10,m_width,m_height,0,
                                 BlackPixel(m_dpy, s), WhitePixel(m_dpy, s));
    m_pix = XCreatePixmap(m_dpy, m_root, m_width, m_height, DefaultDepthOfScreen(scn));

    imlib_context_set_display(m_dpy);
    imlib_context_set_visual(DefaultVisualOfScreen(scn));
    imlib_context_set_colormap(DefaultColormapOfScreen(scn));
    imlib_context_set_drawable(m_pix);

    imlib_render_image_on_drawable(0,0);
    XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap(m_dpy, m_root, m_pix);
    XClearWindow(m_dpy, m_root);
    Atom wmDeleteMessage = XInternAtom(m_dpy, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
    XSetWMProtocols(m_dpy, m_root, &wmDeleteMessage, 1);

    XSelectInput(m_dpy, m_root, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | StructureNotifyMask);
    XMapWindow(m_dpy, m_root);
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        XEvent m_ev;
        XNextEvent(m_dpy, &m_ev);
        /* draw or redraw the window */
        if (m_ev.type == Expose)
        {
            XFillRectangle(m_dpy, m_root, DefaultGC(m_dpy, DefaultScreen(m_dpy)), 20, 20, 10, 10);
        }

    /* exit on key press */
        //usleep(1000000);
        //done = true;
        switch(m_ev.type)
        {
        case KeyPress:
            XDestroyWindow(m_dpy, m_root);
        break;

        case DestroyNotify:
            done = true;
        break;
        case ClientMessage:
            if (m_ev.xclient.data.l[0] == wmDeleteMessage)
            {
                done = true;
            }
        break;
        }
    }

    //XFreePixmap(m_dpy, m_pix);
    //imlib_free_image();
    //XCloseDisplay(m_dpy);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it a splash screen, use extended window manager hints.

```
#include <X11/Xatom.h>

Atom type = XInternAtom(m_dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False);
Atom value = XInternAtom(m_dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_SPLASH", False);
XChangeProperty(m_dpy, m_root, type, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&value), 1);
```

The window then appears without decorations and stays until clicked.

When clicked you get an `UnmapNotify` event, so this what you should use to set done.

To avoid having to get events, add

```
XFlush(m_dpy);
```

after mapping the window to display it and

```
XUnmapWindow(m_dpy, m_root);
```

when you want to get rid of it.

In this example the program just sleeps for 5 seconds before continuing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <Imlib2.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    Imlib_Image  m_img;
    Display     *m_dpy;
    Pixmap       m_pix;
    Window       m_root;
    Screen      *scn;
    int m_width, m_height;
    const char *filename = "w.png";

    m_img = imlib_load_image(filename);
    if(!m_img)
    {
        printf("%s\n","init m_img faild");
    }
    imlib_context_set_image(m_img);
    m_width = imlib_image_get_width();
    m_height = imlib_image_get_height();

    m_dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if(!m_dpy)
    {
        printf("%s\n","open display failed");
    }
    scn = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(m_dpy);
    int s = DefaultScreen(m_dpy);
    m_root = XCreateSimpleWindow(m_dpy, RootWindow(m_dpy,s),10,10,m_width,m_height,0,
                                 BlackPixel(m_dpy, s), WhitePixel(m_dpy, s));
    m_pix = XCreatePixmap(m_dpy, m_root, m_width, m_height, DefaultDepthOfScreen(scn));

    Atom type = XInternAtom(m_dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False);
    Atom value = XInternAtom(m_dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_SPLASH", False);
    XChangeProperty(m_dpy, m_root, type, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&value), 1);

    imlib_context_set_display(m_dpy);
    imlib_context_set_visual(DefaultVisualOfScreen(scn));
    imlib_context_set_colormap(DefaultColormapOfScreen(scn));
    imlib_context_set_drawable(m_pix);

    imlib_render_image_on_drawable(0,0);
    XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap(m_dpy, m_root, m_pix);
    XClearWindow(m_dpy, m_root);
    Atom wmDeleteMessage = XInternAtom(m_dpy, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
    XSetWMProtocols(m_dpy, m_root, &wmDeleteMessage, 1);

    XMapWindow(m_dpy, m_root);
    XFlush(m_dpy);
    sleep(5);
    XUnmapWindow(m_dpy, m_root);
}
```

Comment: It helps a lot and my best to you but I still wanna make it stop just buy a fun() like    mSplash->finish() then it will close but no click the mouse; click mouse means catch events and I've already made it

Comment: I've used a while( !done ) to draw the window while the program goes on it can not break out from the while block . There will be the best thx if you can send me the .cpp to soi_zt@hotmail.com

Comment: Hey man, I'am here to trouble you again !     I've used XDrawString like this : char *msg = "hello world"                                    XDrawString(m_dpy,m_root,DefalutGC(m_dpy,DefaultScreen(m_dpy),1000,50,strlen(msg))； to draw but do not see

Comment: You're drawing on the root GC of the display, you need to use CreateGC to create a GC for your window.

Comment: however, there is only one window which named m_root ,I use Imlib to create "connect the PNG" to the display and I wander if use something to "connect the "char *" to the display 。。。

Comment: Your window is m_root, I'm talking about the root window which is the whole of the display, not just your window.

Comment: I've past my code under blow hope any assistance ,so much thx to U

Answer (score 1):

and this program can have a splash with hello world alse I do not know how to jump out of the while(!done) so much thx to U

g++ -o test_chr test_chr.cpp -lX11

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    Display *d;
    Window w;
    XEvent e;
    const char *msg = "Hello, World!";
    int s;
    bool done = false;

    /* open connection with the server */
    d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (d == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    s = DefaultScreen(d);

    /* create window */
    w = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, RootWindow(d, s), 10, 10, 480, 320, 0,BlackPixel(d, s), WhitePixel(d, s));
    Atom type = XInternAtom(d,"_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False);
    Atom value = XInternAtom(d,"_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_SPLASH", False);
    XChangeProperty(d, w, type, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&value), 1);
    /* register interest in the delete window message */
    Atom wmDeleteMessage = XInternAtom(d, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", False);
    XSetWMProtocols(d, w, &wmDeleteMessage, 1);

    /* select kind of events we are interested in */
    XSelectInput(d, w, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | StructureNotifyMask);

    /* map (show) the window */
    XMapWindow(d, w);
    /* event loop */
    while (!done)
    {
        XNextEvent(d, &e);
        /* draw or redraw the window */
        if (e.type == Expose)
        {
            XDrawString(d, w, DefaultGC(d, s), 50, 50, msg, strlen(msg));
        }

        /* exit on key press */
        switch(e.type)
        {
        case KeyPress:
            XDestroyWindow(d, w);

        break;

        case DestroyNotify:
            done = true;
        break;

        case ClientMessage:
            if (e.xclient.data.l[0] == wmDeleteMessage)
            {
                done = true;
            }
        break;
        }
    }
    /* close connection to server */
    XCloseDisplay(d);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: // while (!done)
// {
//  XNextEvent(d, &e);
//  /* draw or redraw the window */
//  if (e.type == Expose)
//  {
   XDrawString(d, w, DefaultGC(d, s), 50, 50, msg, strlen(msg));
   XFlush(d);
   sleep(10);
//  }  this code does not work only a "empty_white" splash screen on the center of my screen  once I need this program going on (means run code under the while{} ) but still need the splash screen I used a fork() but this need pipe and sth else

Comment: if ( e.type == Expose) { XFlush(d); XDrawString(); sleep(1); } this works and can not jump out of while either